# How to find a polynomial over a finite field if its nonzero roots are given without root multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

We look for a set of polynomials that all of them have the same non-zero roots but with different multiplicities. Suppose we have the following side information about each  polynomial in the set. all polynomials are of degree $\leq n-1$ over finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $n=q-1$.

- The exact degree of the polynomials are known
- Their nonzero distinct roots over $\mathbb{F}_q$ without root multiplicity
- some coefficients of high degree terms (less than half of its coefficients are known)
- Zero can also be a root of these polynomials

How do you find this set of polynomials or one of them? Linear system of equations is not efficient enough for this problem.

**Example:** lets assume $n=10$, $q=11$. All the polynomials in our set $D$ are of degree at least $7$ and at most $9$. All of them have exactly $7$ non-zero distinct roots but the multiplicity of their roots can be different so thats why the degree can be higher than $7$. We know all coefficients $f_7,f_8,f_9$ of these polynomials ($f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f_ix^i$) which means we know the highest non-zero coefficient of the polynomial and so the exact degree of the polynomial. zero is also allowed to be a root of these polynomial.

Comment: Doesn't all of this just give a linear set of equations over $\mathbb F_p$? Do you know how to solve linear equations in general?

Comment: Yes I know this gives a linear system but I need an efficient idea to solve it rather than writing it as a linear system.

Comment: By "efficient", do you mean algorithmic time complexity? Gaussian elimination is already polynomial time, and I doubt you can do much better than that.

Comment: "my problem" Post your original problem instead. This is clearly some "reinterpretation" that you are doing. When you don't have sufficient understanding of a problem, a "reinterpretation" can be turning it into a completely different problem.

Comment: Changing "my" for "this" doesn't hide the fact that this is not what you need. "Some coefficients of high degree". Which? How many? How many roots are given? Learn to formulate a problem, if you are going to hide the original one.

Comment: Thanks @Trebor for your comment. I am looking for a quasi-polynomial time complexity method to solve it. Something like $O(n\log n)$ or $O(n\log^2 n)$ which is possible for structured linear systems. The system that I have is not structured, it is actually a random submatrix of a Vandermonde matrix. by random I mean the chosen rows and columns for the submatrix are not consecutive so it is not invertible.

Comment: Thanks @NDB. I am not trying to hide the original problem, I just need to know what else someone can get from the given information. I will try to add more detail.